# Can't add Playwright to a Dockerized Java app

Tags: docker, dockerfile, playwright, docker-multi-stage-build, playwright-java

I have a spring app that runs with the following dockerfile (used for Tilt locally):

```
FROM amazoncorretto:21-alpine-jdk AS builder
# Install "entr" package using apk package manager
RUN apk update && \
    apk add entr
FROM public.ecr.aws/amazoncorretto/amazoncorretto:21
COPY --from=builder /lib/ld-musl-aarch64.so.1 /lib/ld-musl-aarch64.so.1
COPY --from=builder /usr/bin/entr /usr/bin/entr
ENV MAIN_OPTS ''
RUN yum install -y tar && mkdir -p /opt/demo/
ADD BOOT-INF/lib /opt/demo/lib
ADD META-INF /opt/demo/META-INF
ADD BOOT-INF/classes /opt/demo
WORKDIR /opt/demo/
ENTRYPOINT java $JAVA_OPTS -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=*:5013 -cp .:./lib/* io.demo.DemoApplication $MAIN_OPTS
EXPOSE 8080
```

I would like to head Playwright's headless browser (version 1.40.0) so I can PDF export my site.
Added ENV PLAYWRIGHT_SKIP_BROWSER_DOWNLOAD 1 to my dockerfile so it doesn't download the browser (headless).
I need to add to my dockerfile the playwright image so it knows to install everything it needs on the docker image.
tried the following things (separately), without success:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/playwright/java:v1.40.0-jammy as playwright


FROM apify/actor-node-playwright:16


FROM mcr.microsoft.com/playwright/python:v1.40.0-focal
```

Got various errors, including:

```
entr: exec java: No such file or directory

failed to install browsers

failed to create driver
```

Without anything from above (except the skip browser download flag) I get this error:

```
Failed to read message from driver, pipe closed
```

My question is, how do I make a multi-stage docker file on top of my current build, so the image will have playwright on it?

Notice I'm not using Playwright for tests in this case, if it matters.